# In a list of objects how do I subtract a field of one object with the same field of another object in the same List in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, object

I have the following case classes:

```
case class AgeDiff(serviceLocation: ServiceLocation, daysBehind: Option[Long])
case class ServiceLocation(
    environment: String,
    service: String,
    pool: String,
    region: String
)
```

And I have a `List[AgeDiff]`

There are only two possible environments in this list for the `serviceLocation`

`QA` & `Prod`

an example of the list could be:

```
val ageDiffList = List(
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(6)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(7)
    ),AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "b-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(8)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "b-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(10)
    )
)
```

I want to return a new `List[AgeDiff]` where I subtract the `daysBehind`  from all the AgeDiff's that have a `serviceLocation` in `prod` from the ones that have a `serviceLocation` in `qa`

for instance when List subtraction takes place it will look like this:

```
val ageDiffList = List(
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(6)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(1)

    ),AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "b-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(8)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "b-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(2)
    )
)
```

### The conditions are:

- I want to do the subtraction for AgeDiffs of the same `pool`,
  `region`,`service`.

For Example:

```
   AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(6)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(7)
    )
```

not

```
   AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(6)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "b-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(7)
    )
```

- If the days diff are different in the same service,
  **do not** subtract

for example:

```
   AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("qa", "a-service", "poolb", "us-west-3"),
      Some(6)
    ),
    AgeDiff(
      ServiceLocation("prod", "a-service", "poolC", "us-west-4"),
      Some(7)
    )
```

unless they have the same pool and region and service or they days behind match then they can be collapsed. However, service name **MUST BE** the same in order to subtract.

- If `daysBehind` is `None` Then do not compare and leave them as is

Comment: So if the list has only `environment` values of `"qa"`, or if the list has all unique `service` values, then there would be no change. Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: And if the list starts with a `"qa"` entry followed by 7 matching `"prod"` entries, would the subtraction happen once (the 1st `"prod"`) or 7 times?

Comment: 7 times since the regions may differ and they also can contain different  `daysBehind` values .

Comment: What should happen if there are `None`s in `daysBehind`?

Comment: then don't subtract them and leave them as is

Answer (score 1):

OK, the specifications are still a bit vague, but I'll have a go at it.

```
val newADList =
  ageDiffList.foldLeft((List[AgeDiff](),Map[ServiceLocation,Long]())){
    case ((acc, mp)
         ,ad@AgeDiff(sl@ServiceLocation("qa",_,_,_),less)) =>
      (ad::acc, mp+(sl.copy(environment="prod") -> less.getOrElse(0L)))
    case ((acc, mp)
         ,ad@AgeDiff(sl@ServiceLocation("prod",_,_,_),Some(x))) =>
      (ad.copy(daysBehind = Some(x - mp.getOrElse(sl,0L)))::acc, mp)
    case ((acc, mp), ad) => (ad::acc, mp)
  }._1.reverse
```

This assumes that a `"qa"` with a `daysBehind` value of `None` is **not** ignored but, instead, it effectively turns off the subtractions in all following `"prod"` elements with a matching `SeviceLocation` value.